# Submitting multiple fields data with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So i have this http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mDfQT/10/

```
$('.add_options').on('click', function () {
    $('#variants').append('<div class="some_id"><input type="text" id="prop_name" class="prop_name" placeholder="Property name"><a href="#" class="remover">Remove</a></div>');
    var size = parseInt($('#variants').attr("data-size"), 10) + 1;
    $('#variants').attr("data-size", size);
    $("#count").text(size);
});
$('#variants').on('click', '.remover', function () {
    $(this).closest('.some_id').hide();
    var size = parseInt($('#variants').attr("data-size"), 10) - 1;
    $('#variants').attr("data-size", size);
    $("#count").text(size);
});
```

Users can add as much fields as they want, after the user is done updating the values of the fields(number n), i would like to use ajax to submit the data.
My question is, what's the most efficient way to get the data from all the textboxes while leaving each data field distinguishable(So that i can update my db).
Ps:It's actually two text boxes per row, so when the user clicks add more it appends two texboxes(property name and property type) at once, the fiddle has only property name.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the serialize jQuery function: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

wrap the inputs in a form and then you can on submit serialize the data and post your ajax.

```
var dataToBeSubmitted = $('form').serialize()
```

Comment: thanks but i'm still trying to debate putting it in a form due to some rails form in form probe.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code

1. ID is unique, only once per page
2. Your HTML is not valid - `ul` tag shoud has only `li` tag
3. If you want use `.serialize` method, your `input` must have `name` attribute

But if we forget this bugs here is solution:

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function () {
    var data = $('#variants .prop_name').serialize();
    console.log(data);
});
```

**[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/mDfQT/11/)**

Comment: Instead of thanking, mark one of answer as accepted / upvote; or ask what is not working or what you dont understand on it